# WinRT ZipArchiv include Folder informations

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

With [Ziparchiv.CreateEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158346.aspx) I add files to a zipStream

But is there a way to create also folders?

I want to zip a folder tree to a zip. Currently I can't see a way to have the sametree in the zip file.

The only soultion I currently have , to not loose the information, is to create somekind of reference file which contrains the relative pathes.

Is there a way to have folders in WinRT ZipArchivs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution when writing the sample code.
Because i didn't find this here i consider adding the question also hoping that this will help someone.
If this one is a duplicate feel free to delete it or link it to the pre existing question :-)

When calling [CreateEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158346.aspx) the path can be prefixed to the filename.
The following code sets foo as the folder in the zipfile in the archive

```
 zipArchive.CreateEntry(@"foo\" + fileToCompress.Name,CompressionLevel.Optimal);
```